# How to populate full calendar with json data

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm using FUllCALENDAR CSS template to design a meeting calendar.

 

I have a servlet class called CalendarController. While I run this it gives me out put like this.

```
{"events":[{"id":1,"title":"1","start":"2015-11-11 05:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-11 06:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"},
{"id":2,"title":"1","start":"2015-11-18 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 06:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":3,"title":"1","start":"2015-11-18 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 06:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":4,"title":"2","start":"2015-11-19 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-19 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":5,"title":"2","start":"2015-11-12 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-12 06:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":7,"title":"lkj","start":"2015-11-18 06:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":8,"title":"lkj","start":"2015-11-18 06:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":9,"title":"lkj","start":"2015-11-18 06:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":10,"title":"lkj","start":"2015-11-18 06:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":11,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-18 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":12,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-19 07:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-19 07:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":13,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-19 07:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-19 07:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":14,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-12 07:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-12 07:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":15,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-12 07:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-12 07:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":16,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-12 07:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-12 07:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":17,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-12 07:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-12 07:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":18,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-11 06:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-11 06:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":19,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-11 05:30:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-11 06:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":20,"title":"My Topic","start":"2015-11-11 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-11 07:00:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}, 
{"id":6,"title":"lhsd","start":"2015-11-18 06:00:00.0",
"end":"2015-11-18 06:30:00.0","url":"http://google.com/"}]}
```

I usually use dummy data to populate my fullCalendar.jsp

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    eventRender: function(event, element) {
                        element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                            showDialog('#dialog1');
                        });
                        // alert shows up in linux chrome, but messes up draggable
                    },
                    minTime: '07:00:00',
                    maxTime: '21:00:00',
                    defaultTime: '08am',
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    editable: false,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            title: 'All Day Event',
                            start: '2015-11-01',
                            textColor: '#63A223',
                            color: 'rgba(122, 214, 29, 0.31)'

                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            title: 'Long Event',
                            start: '2015-11-02',
                            end: '2015-11-05',
                            textColor: '#63A223',
                            color: 'rgba(122, 214, 29, 0.31)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: '2015-11-07T14:00:00',
                            textColor: '#ce352c',
                            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: '2015-11-06T13:00:00',
                            textColor: '#ce352c',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            title: 'Conference',
                            start: '2015-11-01',
                            end: '2015-11-03',
                            textColor: '#ce352c',
                            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            title: 'Meeting',
                            start: '2015-11-04T10:30:00',
                            end: '2015-11-04T12:30:00',
                            textColor: '#63A223',
                            color: 'rgba(122, 214, 29, 0.31)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 7,
                            title: 'Lunch',
                            start: '2015-11-02T12:00:00',
                            textColor: '#999900',
                            color: 'rgba(243, 210, 64, 0.4)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 8,
                            title: 'Meeting',
                            start: '2015-11-02T14:30:00',
                            textColor: '#ce352c',
                            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 9,
                            title: 'Happy Hour',
                            start: '2015-11-04T17:30:00',
                            end: '2015-11-04T16:30:00',
                            textColor: '#ce352c',
                            color: 'rgba(243, 210, 64, 0.4)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 10,
                            title: 'Dinner',
                            start: '2015-11-02T20:00:00',
                            textColor: '#ce352c',
                            color: 'rgba(255, 187, 56, 0.4);'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 11,
                            title: 'Birthday Party',
                            start: '2015-11-03T07:00:00',
                            textColor: '#999900',
                            color: 'rgba(243, 210, 64, 0.4)'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 12,
                            title: 'Click for Google',
                            url: 'http://google.com/',
                            start: '2015-11-06',
                            textColor: '#63A223',
                            color: 'rgba(122, 214, 29, 0.31)'
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
```

Here is that output.

[image]

I have no idea how to connect these two and populate the fullCalendar.jsp.

I tried JQuery.getJSON() method but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add `calendarcontroller` output as a source you can use `cal.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source )` where `source` is the  `events` json. Also from [official documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/)

> Source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option. Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the calendar.

So you can feed the source by getting the JSON in client side by making ajax call here.

Another use case,
If you want to place one event at a time dynamically you can use

Assume the output of the servlet is retrieved in client side and is assigned to a variable called `op`

```
var allEventsConf = op.events;
allEventsConf.forEach(function(conf){
    cal.fullCalendar("renderEvent", {
        id: conf.id,
        title: conf.title,
        start: conf.startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        end: conf.endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        url: conf.link
    }, true);
});
```

Checkout the **EventData** and **EventRendering** section of the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)

Comment: What is conf?? is that a parameter name